# How to recursively print all files under the current working directory from Vim?

Tags: vim

I’m currently using MacVim and I’d like to print out all the files in my working tree. Is there a way to simply do this, perhaps using the `hardcopy` command?

Comment: `:qa` will close all open files...I wonder if `a` can modify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A convenient way to execute a command for a group of files is to
(1) collect the list of their names, define it as the new argument list
(see `:help arglist`), and then (2) iterate the command over that list.

**1.** To perform the first step, use the `:args` command with
a wildcard matching the desired files. For example,

```
:args ./**/*
```

sets the argument list to the names of all files in the current
directory and its subdirectories; similarly,

```
:args /tmp/**/*.{c,h}
```

selects all `.c` and `.h` files in `/tmp` and its subdirectories.
For details about wildcard syntax, see `:help wildcard`.

If the path to the root of a subtree containing files to print is
unknown beforehand and is built by a script, use the command

```
:exe 'args' join(map(split(glob(p . '/**/*'), '\n'), 'fnameescape(v:val)'))
```

where the variable `p` is supposed to contain the path to that
root directory.

**2.** For sending files in the argument list to the printer, execute
the `:hardcopy` command for those files using the `:argdo` command:

```
:argdo hardcopy!
```

The `!` specifier suppresses the modal dialog for selecting printing
parameters.

A more complicated command can be used to print each file to
a separate PostScript document located at the same directory
as that file:

```
:argdo hardcopy! >%:p.ps
```

Here the name of a printed file is concatenated with the `.ps` suffix
to get the name of a corresponding PostScript file (see
`:help cmdline-special`).

For speeding up the `:argdo` argument command, Vim ignores the
`Syntax` autocommand event by adding it to the `eventignore` list.
This implies that if `Syntax` autocommands had not been run for
a file in the argument list before the `:hardcopy` command is
`:argdo`ne, the corresponding printed document would not be
syntax highlighted (despite `syntax:y` being set in `printoptions`).
To execute `Syntax` autocommands for all files in the argument
list, use the following command first:

```
:argdo set ei-=Syntax | do Syntax
```

To do this in the same run as printing, concatenate the two
commands:

```
:argdo set ei-=Syntax | do Syntax | hardcopy! >%:p.ps
```

Comment: @ib. Follow up question on this one.  I can't seem to get syntax highlighting to work when I use this command.  From what I can tell, it does it for the first one but none of the next ones it prints to PostScript.  Wondering, why is that?  I've tried `set printoptions=syntax:y"` in my vimrc but doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Phil:  That is because of the fact that `Syntax` autocommands are disabled when the command passed to `:argdo` is run.  If the `Syntax` autocommand event was not triggered for a file in the argument list (for example, due to it had not been displayed, just had been mentioned in the argument list), then there is no syntax highlighting for that file.  To ensure that syntax highlighting is turned on for all files in the argument list, use the command added in the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Sorry, I misunderstood before.

To print all, say php and C# files in your working directory:

```
:args ./*.{cs,php} **/*.{cs,php}
:argdo ha
```

Comment: Simply `:args **/*.{cs,php}` would do it, IIRC.